# Carrying a Carradice Camper Longflap when off the bike

Tags: cargo, luggage, bags

I'm currently considering getting a Carradice Camper Longflap saddlebag as I've heard good things about it and like the idea of being able to carry a lot of stuff in a saddle bag.  Just one thing concerns me, and I haven't been able to find out that answer elsewhere:

Is there a handle or something on the bag?  If not, is it easy to fit some sort of carrying mechanism, or is the bag meant to be just left on the bike?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A picture could be nice if possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two straps that attach the Carradice bag to the saddle will need to be re-threaded and buckled up each time you remove and re-attach the bag, so it's probably not the most convenient choice for your usage.  I remember seeing quick-release systems for these bags, but you'll have to check if they work for the massive Camper version.  There is no actual handle either, but I suppose you could rig one up between the two straps.

Answer (score 4):

I've got the Carradice Camper Longflap with the quick release rack recommended on the website. I got a leather strap off an old leather bag which clips easily onto the leather hooks which are placed on either side of the Carradice bag. I don't know if that's what they're meant for but it works well.